# get post of category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm Using WP 3.4.2 , a child theme of twentyeleven.  I have created a category called "featured media".

I want to get and display posts which have this category.
I checked around before coming here, I found variations of the same answer, in forums.  Generally I am advised to write:

```
$args = array('category'=> x); 
get_posts($args);
```

I don't know the category id. Some forums have advised me to go to  Dashboard--> posts -->categories, find my category  and hover over the "Edit" link, and read the category id from the status bar. My browser shows me this address: `localhost/myblog/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&tag_ID=7&post_type=post`

This apparently means my category id is 7.  The above code returns and empty array.  This has become really frustrating for me. I believe the method is correct. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting global $post?

Heres the WordPress example from their website:

```
 <ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Thanks for the code.  It didn't really solve my problem, but still very kind of you to share. Destroying the category and rebuilding it with new title was the last step I took before the array started to behave as expected.